# what do you say when someone is at your door?

Tags: expression-choice

When a mail man knock at the door, I was sleeping. I was going to put on my clothes, then open the door. Then I said: "coming". I suddenly felt like it was "come in".
So what do you say when you want to let them open the door themselves and come in?
What do you say when you want tell them you are going to open the door for them soon?

Comment: "Honey, get the door!"

Comment: "Be right there!"

Answer (score 3):

In general, in vague, confusing, or awkward situations, say exactly what you mean. An earnest, awkward person is much more pleasant to work with than an inscrutable one!

To tell someone that you're on your way, you can say:

> "I'll be right there!"
>
> "Just a minute!"
>
> "One second!"
>
> "Hold on, I'll be right there!"
>
> "I'll be out in just a minute!"
>
> etc.

It really just has to convey that you *know they're there*, but cannot respond as fast as you would otherwise feel proper. This leaves them feeling like you're busy, but on top of things, as opposed to rude or disorganized.

To tell someone to let themselves in, you can say:

> "Feel free to let yourself in!"
>
> "Come on in!"
>
> "The door's open!"
>
> etc.

It really just has to convey that while you appreciate their politeness in not assuming they can intrude, you would find it more convenient if they did on this occasion. Otherwise, they might perceive you as inhospitable, disorganized, or simply get fed up and leave!

Comment: *It's not locked* is one that I'd use to mean "come in".